# How to add manually related posts to a post?

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a blog site in php where users can add manually related posts to a post.

I thought to use an autoincrement integer for all posts related.

This is the table:

```
Blog:
-id
-related ( it's 0 if there aren't related posts or it contain an autoincremet integer that it is the same for all posts related )
-id_user
-title
-body
-date
```

I prefer not to use a "related table" if possible to avoid complex queries.

So I need a way to get an auto increment integer in this case or you can suggest me other solutions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not have a second table? It's probably the most robust solution, and it doesn't complify your queries much at all.

You should have a second table, `related-posts`, with two fields: `original` and `related`.

Neither are unique, so the following is possible (assuming 1,2,3,4 are post IDs)

```
o | r
--+--
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 3
2 | 4
4 | 1
```

When you need to find posts related to post 1 (for example), you query

```
SELECT `related` FROM `related-posts` WHERE `original` = 1;
```

This will give you all related post IDs.

---

This kind of relationship is called **many-to-many** relationship, one post can have many related posts, and one post can be related to many original posts.

Comment: Exactly, that way complexity and data redundancy is actually reduced.

Comment: So in this case when a user is posting, so I need to do 2 queries ( insert in the blog table and insert in the related table ) ?

Comment: @xRobot: No, only when you add a related post you update the `related-posts` table. It's a completely separate part of the original table.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set `related` as NULL, and after that you can check, whether it's NULL — then there is no related posts.

To select all related posts:

```
SELECT * FROM Blog where related=:blog_id
```

Comment: ok but if related is not null, how can I get the autoincrement integer that is unique for all posts related ?

Comment: just check quantity of related posts and write it down to some column when you add related blog: `select count(id) from Blog where related=:blog_id` 
Ofcourse, it's suitable only if you use models.

Comment: @IlyaDoroshin You don't *just* write stuff down to database.

Comment: @Chibueze Opata I don't know why does he need autoincrement for related posts.